# Can I change which user is automatically logged in based on the time?

Tags: login, scripts, auto-login

I have a personal and work account on my machine. I'd like the automatic login to use the following logic (if you'll pardon my Python)... is this possible?

```
if (time < 5pm) and (day in workdays):
    log in to work account
else:
    log in to personal account
```

Answer (score 1):

Which user is automatically logged in is stored in the `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` file.  You'd have to write a script to update that file and use cron to call it at the appropriate time.

Comment: would it be possible to do that as part of the boot-up process?

Comment: Sure.  Put it in your /etc/rc.local script.